# Is it possible to return a map of key values using gremlin scala

Tags: scala, graph-databases, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Currently i have two gremlin queries which will fetch two different values and i am populating in a map.
Scenario : A->B , A->C , A->D

My queries below,

1. `graph.V().has(ID,A).out().label().toList()`

Fetch the list of outE labels of A .

**Result : List(B,C,D)**

2. `graph.traversal().V().has("ID",A).outE("interference").as("x").otherV().has("ID",B).select("x").values("value").headOption()`

Given A and B , get the egde property value (A->B)

**Return : 10**

Is it possible that i can combine both there queries to get a return as **Map[(B,10)(C,11)(D,12)]**

I am facing some performance issue when i have two queries. Its taking more time

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this but I managed to get something with the following traversal:

```
gremlin> graph.traversal().V().has("ID","A").outE("interference").as("x").otherV().has("ID").label().as("y").select("x").by("value").as("z").select("y", "z").select(values);
==>[B,1]
==>[C,2]
```

I would wait for more answers though as I suspect there is a better traversal out there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `select(values);` Here the `values` is not getting resolved. Why do we need `select(values)`. Here A has many OutE edges . We need to get OtherV() of all and its edge property value.

Comment: `select(values);` can actually be omitted if you like. I just do it to get rid of the `z` and `y` labels of the select.

This traversal is getting the property on the edge. `select("x").by("value")` this selects `x` which is the edge and `.by("value")` tells it to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Below is working in scala

```
val b = StepLabel[Edge]()
val y = StepLabel[Label]()
val z = StepLabel[Integer]() 

graph.traversal().V().has("ID",A).outE("interference").as(b)
        .otherV().label().as(y)
        .select(b).values("name").as(z)
        .select((y,z)).toMap[String,Integer]
```

This will return Map[String,Int]

Comment: You don't need `otherV` - you traversed `outE`, so to get to the adjacent vertex you can just do `inV`. Use `otherV` when traversing across `bothE` where you need to backtrack to make sure that you don't traverse back to where you came.

Comment: @stephen mallette Even with both `otherV` and `inV` time taken for fetching the data takes almost the same time. its taking ~19 secs to fetch 4000 vertices each having 10 Edges . Is there any i can still optimize it.

Comment: `inV` still incurs less overhead, so I would prefer that in any case. not sure i can make it go faster just from a Gremlin perspective. the double `select` seems unnecessary. i would prefer: `g.V().has("ID", "A").outE("interference").as('x').inV().label().as('y').select('y','x').by().by('name')`